# ANR in Android - Application Not Responding

Tags: android, memory-leaks, crash, anr

please fin the stack trace below. ANR occuring some times in screen, this is the stack trace i got in logcats. we are doing some bitmap processing before this, so not sure if its related to memmory or something.

please fin the stack trace below. ANR occuring some times in screen, this is the stack trace i got in logcats. we are doing some bitmap processing before this, so not sure if its related to memmory or something.

```
 ANR in <package-name of the app>
                                                                                                    `.       enter code here`enter code here`PID: 24329
                                                                                                    
  Reason: executing service <package- name>/com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService
                                                                                                    ErrorId: e9f15d1d-0766-45d0-8994-a8d255c229b8
                                                                                                    Frozen: false
                                                                                                    Load: 4.7 / 2.68 / 2.29
                                                                                                    ----- Output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
                                                                                                    some avg10=4.35 avg60=9.21 avg300=4.40 total=71024275
                                                                                                    full avg10=2.93 avg60=6.41 avg300=3.06 total=47635616
                                                                                                    ----- End output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
                                                                                                    
                                                                                                    CPU usage from 151568ms to -1ms ago (2023-04-26 13:18:05.803 to 2023-04-26 13:20:37.373):
                                                                                                      46% 24329/com.awarex.mref.qa: 33% user + 13% kernel / faults: 1705406 minor 132468 major
                                                                                                      17% 129/kswapd0: 0% user + 17% kernel
                                                                                                      9.6% 405/surfaceflinger: 2.4% user + 7.2% kernel / faults: 86063 minor 11314 major
                                                                                                      4.5% 589/system_server: 0.7% user + 3.8% kernel / faults: 84144 minor 55149 major
                                                                                                      2.3% 444/adbd: 0.6% user + 1.6% kernel / faults: 63642 minor 9370 major
                                                                                                      2.1% 13442/kworker/u8:0-events_unbound: 0% user + 2.1% kernel
                                                                                                      2% 386/android.hardware.sensors@2.1-service.multihal: 0% user + 1.9% kernel / faults: 87470 minor 33681 major
                                                                                                      1.6% 380/android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.4-service: 0.4% user + 1.2% kernel / faults: 36287 minor 14750 major
                                                                                                      1.6% 24754/kworker/u8:2-phy1: 0% user + 1.6% kernel
                                                                                                      1.6% 22796/com.google.android.inputmethod.latin: 1.2% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 64232 minor 667 major
                                                                                                      1.5% 786/com.android.systemui: 0.5% user + 1% kernel / faults: 22883 minor 5165 major
                                                                                                      1.4% 22464/kworker/u9:2-blk_crypto_wq: 0% user + 1.4% kernel
                                                                                                      1.2% 22483/kworker/u9:4-fscrypt_read_queue: 0% user + 1.2% kernel
                                                                                                      1.1% 22466/kworker/u8:5-loop0: 0% user + 1.1% kernel
                                                                                                      0.3% 21633/kworker/u9:1-fscrypt_read_queue: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
                                                                                                      0.9% 218/logd: 0.2% user + 0.7% kernel / faults: 2079 minor 333 major
                                                                                                      0.9% 22425/kworker/u8:1-events_unbound: 0% user + 0.9% kernel
                                                                                                      0.6% 365/android.hardware.audio.service: 0.1% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 270 minor 14 major
                                                                                                      0.6% 22515/com.google.android.gms.persistent: 0.2% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 31194 minor 5330 major
                                                                                                      0.6% 401/audioserver: 0.3% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 953 minor 55 major
                                                                                                      0.5% 24711/kworker/0:1-events: 0% user + 0.5% kernel
                                                                                                      0.4% 18376/transport: 0% user + 0.4% kernel / faults: 11254 minor 5853 major
                                                                                                      0.4% 17357/kworker/u9:0-fscrypt_read_queue: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
                                                                                                      0.3% 12/ksoftirqd/0: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
                                                                                                      0.3% 455/logcat: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 3955 minor 113 major
                                                                                                      0.3% 24138/com.android.chrome: 0% user + 0.3% kernel / faults: 7034 minor 4756 major
                                                                                                      0.2% 908/com.android.networkstack.process: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 5903 minor 4842 major
                                                                                                      0.2% 22649/com.google.android.gms: 0.1% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 6250 minor 1500 major
                                                                                                      0.2% 22514/kworker/0:2-events: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                                                                                                      0.1% 981/com.android.phone: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 5680 minor 2965 major
                                                                                                      0.1% 14661/logcat: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 3149 minor 112 major
                                                                                                      0.1% 564/logcat: 0% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 3129 minor 116 major
                                                                                                      0.1% 24/ksoftirqd/1: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                      0.1% 23782/com.google.android.permissioncontroller: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 7322 minor 8 major
                                                                                                      0.1% 30/ksoftirqd/2: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                      0.1% 13/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                      0.1% 47/kcompactd0: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                      0.1% 22534/kworker/3:1-virtio_vsock: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                      0.1% 140/kworker/2:2-virtio_vsock: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                      0.1% 146/sugov:1: 0% user + 0.1% kernel
                                                                                                      0% 147/sugov:2: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                      0% 36/ksoftirqd/3: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                      0% 145/sugov:0: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                      0% 148/sugov:3: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                      0% 19867/kworker/1:2-cgroup_destroy: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                      0% 371/android.hardware.camera.provider@2.7-service-google: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 8875 minor 46 major
                                                                                                      0% 23672/com.google.android.ext.services: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2085 minor
                                                                                                      0% 389/android.hardware.wifi@1.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1959 minor 595 major
                                                                                                      0% 153/kworker/0:1H-kblockd: 0% user + 0% kernel
2023-04-26 13:20:38.913   589-25145 ActivityManager         system_process                       E    0% 219/lmkd: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                      0% 361/statsd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1172 minor 279 major
                                                                                                      0% 362/netd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2464 minor 587 major
                                                                                                      0% 261/jbd2/dm-32-8: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                      0% 457/cameraserver: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1011 minor 62 major
                                                                                                      0% 179/kworker/1:1H-kblockd: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                      0% 356/dhcpclient: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 151 minor 24 major
                                                                                                      0% 379/android.hardware.graphics.allocator@3.0-service: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 38 minor
                                                                                                      0% 103/kworker/2:1H-kblockd: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                      0% 22980/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:interactor: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 1050 minor 106 major
                                                                                                      0% 1/init: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 54 minor 76 major
                                                                                                      0% 156/kworker/3:1H-kblockd: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                      0% 173/ueventd: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 346 minor 148 major
                                                                                                      0% 392/android.hardware.power-service.example: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 447 minor 82 major
                                                                                                      0% 492/wificond: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 584 minor 37 major
                                                                                                      0% 494/libgoldfish-rild: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 798 minor 243 major
                                                                                                      0% 840/android.hardware.gnss@2.0-service.ranchu: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 249 minor 89 major
                                                                                                      0% 15903/psimon: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                      0% 22533/com.google.android.apps.nexuslauncher: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 409 minor 2 major
                                                                                                      0% 23141/android.process.acore: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 742 minor
                                                                                                      0% 220/servicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 139 minor 21 major
                                                                                                      0% 221/hwservicemanager: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 247 minor 71 major
                                                                                                      0% 227/vold: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 81 minor 24 major
                                                                                                      0% 453/traced: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 151 minor 4 major
                                                                                                      0% 507/android.hardware.biometrics.fingerprint@2.1-service: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 97 minor 16 major
                                                                                                      0% 778/wpa_supplicant: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 161 minor 53 major
                                                                                                      0% 870/com.android.bluetooth: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 249 minor 10 major
                                                                                                      0% 22601/com.google.process.gservices: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 702 minor 23 major
                                                                                                     +0% 25028/kworker/u8:3-events_unbound: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                     +0% 25031/kworker/u8:4-kverityd: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                     +0% 25032/kworker/u8:6-kverityd: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                     +0% 25037/kworker/u9:3-blk_crypto_wq: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                     +0% 25042/kworker/u8:7-events_unbound: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                     +0% 25043/kworker/u8:8-kverityd: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                     +0% 25063/com.google.android.gms.unstable: 0% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                    32% TOTAL: 9.9% user + 15% kernel + 3.8% iowait + 2.3% irq + 1% softirq
                                                                                                    CPU usage from 30ms to 259ms later (2023-04-26 13:20:37.401 to 2023-04-26 13:20:37.631):
                                                                                                      111% 24329/com.awarex.mref.qa: 97% user + 14% kernel / faults: 17132 minor
                                                                                                        92% 24329/.awarex.mref.qa: 87% user + 4.8% kernel
                                                                                                        9.7% 24487/RenderThread: 4.8% user + 4.8% kernel
                                                                                                        4.8% 24494/FrameMetricsAgg: 0% user + 4.8% kernel
                                                                                                      18% 405/surfaceflinger: 4.5% user + 13% kernel
                                                                                                        4.5% 466/RenderEngine: 0% user + 4.5% kernel
                                                                                                      9% 589/system_server: 0% user + 9% kernel / faults: 303 minor
                                                                                                        9% 25145/AnrConsumer: 0% user + 9% kernel
                                                                                                      4.3% 13/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 4.3% kernel
                                                                                                      4.4% 218/logd: 0% user + 4.4% kernel / faults: 1 minor
                                                                                                      4.4% 380/android.hardware.graphics.composer@2.4-service: 0% user + 4.4% kernel
                                                                                                        4.4% 380/composer@2.4-se: 4.4% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                      4.5% 444/adbd: 4.5% user + 0% kernel / faults: 609 minor
                                                                                                        4.5% 444/adbd: 4.5% user + 0% kernel
                                                                                                      4.6% 13442/kworker/u8:0-kverityd: 0% user + 4.6% kernel
                                                                                                    40% TOTAL: 26% user + 12% kernel + 1.1% irq
```

Answer (score 0):

See description for ANRs https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr

My guess would be that you are doing this mentioned bitmap processing on main thread (inside this Scheduler mentioned) and not on background? But it is hard to say without your code.

You can also try to use StrictMode, probably looking for slowCall - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode#noteSlowCall(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

Identify the places in your code where the app’s main thread is busy for more than 5 seconds. Look for suspicious use cases in your app and try to reproduce the ANR.
This can happen because of the service you are running. Try Running this task on the other thread or thread handle. You can use the following  code

```
HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("MyHandlerThread");
handlerThread.start();
// Now get the Looper from the HandlerThread
// NOTE: This call will block until the HandlerThread gets control and 
initializes its Looper
Looper looper = handlerThread.getLooper();
```

You can start working on the looper thread.

Other related issue can be found in below line (official ANR issue link)

https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr#slow-code-on-main